# mpf.plot - extending line joining two points

Tags: plot, mplfinance

I am using the follow code to join the lower points of two bars together (the blue bold line):

from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.dates as mpl_dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpf.plot(data,hlines=dict(hlines=hlines_carrier,colors=['g','r'],linestyle='-.'),type='candle',alines=two_points)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNOSX.png)

However, I would like to the line to extend onto the right and touch the y-axis. What codes I should change in order to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question can be found by [**clicking here**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/278#issuecomment-713279500).

#### There is now a more detailed answer, with a link to code examples, that can be found by [**clicking here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65941656/1639359).