# Python Pandas Dataframe: How to get Trend Lines data from existing dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithmic-trading, trading

I would like to be able to create columns containing trend line data, from two points from my other columns, e.g. CLOSE price to CLOSE price 5 days later.

I would like the trend line to look forward and backwards, extending past the 2 points it is plotted from.

Right now I am NOT bothered about plotting them in mplfinance or matplotlib, I just want the trend line numbers so that I can work with them.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to determine the constants in the formula for a straight line, and use the formula to extend your trend line forward and/or backward.  The formula for a straight line is:

```
y = mx + b
```

where `m` is the *slope* and `b` is the *y-intercept* (the value of `y` when `x == 0`).

This formula assumes that both x and y are continuous.

---

Given two points (two x,y pairs), `x1`,`y1` and `x2`,`y2`, first calculate the slope:

```
slope = (y2-y1) / (x2-x1)
```

Then use either of the two points to calculate the y-intercept:

```
y-intercept = y1 - slope*x1
```

Now you can use `y = mx + b` to calculate the straight line `y` for all relevant values of `x`

---

#### With time-series data, there are two problems with the above:

---

***The first problem is*** in a time series **`y`** is typically a **`float`** while **`x`** is typically some flavor of **`datetime`** object.  This means the slope `(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)` would be a `float` divided by a `DatetimeDelta`, which most programming languages won't allow (unless you can override the division operator; but if so, with what algorithm?).

***The solution*** to this problem is to first convert the datetimes into a `float` representation that is proportional and continuous with respect to time (for example, UNIX time, or matplotlib datetime).  Now you can calculate the slope and y-intercept.

---

***The second problem*** happens if your time series is *discontinuous with time*.  This is common with trade data ***if you choose to ignore non-trading days***.  Ignoring non-trading days causes the x-axis to be discontinuous with time.  This means that the slope calculation `(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)` will be incorrect.

***There are two solutions*** to this discontinuity problem:

1. Don't worry about it because for short periods of time, even with some discontinuities, the slope calculation ***may*** *be a close enough approximation*.
2. If the non-trading days are completely missing from your data frame, recognize that, while the data may be discontinuous with resepect to time, ***it is continuous with respect to*** *the row number of your dataframe*.  Therefore the slope can be calculated using the dataframe row numbers in the denominator.

---

#### [**A more detailed discussion, along with some code examples and plots, can be found by clicking here**.](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/scratch_pad/trend_line_extrapolation.ipynb)

hth

Comment: Thank you! Informative and helpful as always, just like over at the github for mplfinance :)